# How to use Xcom within python script file executed by BashOperator

Tags: python, airflow

I am executing a python script file using a Bash Operator as following:

```
op = BashOperator(task_id='python',
                  bash_command='python3 py_script.py')
```

In the python file, I want to send a value to xcom if a condition is met in a loop, something like:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 2:
        print(i)
        xcom_push('hello')
```

Since it is in a loop and I want it to continue after i reach 2, I can't use a `return`. I have tried with:

```
from airflow.models import XCom

context['ti'].xcom_push('hello')
kwargs['ti'].xcom_push('hello')
```

But in both cases I receive an error like `NameError: name 'kwargs' is not defined`

What would be the solution? Thanks

Comment: which airflow version are you using?
Also, instead of using BashOperator why not use PythonOperator. There you can invoke you r python functions via `python_callable`

Comment: version 1.10.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `do_xcom_push=True` in `BashOperator` then the last line written to stdout by the bash command will be pushed to an XCom ([docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/_api/airflow/operators/bash_operator/index.html?highlight=bashoperator#airflow.operators.bash_operator.BashOperator)).

So, if after `print(i)` in your `py_script.py` no other lines are printed then the string representation of `i` will be pushed to an XCom for the `pythonk` task.

Note 1: In Airflow 1.10, the argument name is `xcom_push` and not `do_xcom_push`.

Note 2: In Airflow 2.x, `do_xcom_push=True` is the default setting.